# get pose(x,y) of any unoccupied cell from 2D occupancy grid

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, ros-melodic, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wish to be able to calculate the pose(x,y) of any unoccupied grid in the occupancy grid from the `occupancyGrid` message type [here](http://docs.ros.org/en/lunar/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) . I wish to use the map `int8[ ] data` which contains the probability of occupancy of each grid. I need to do so for an algorithm I'm working on.
Here are several snippets on how I plan to accomplish this, please be aware that alot of the code before and inbetween have been skipped to cut out information unimportant to the focus of this question:

```
   ...............................
    self.occ_gridmap = rospy.wait_for_message("/map", OccupancyGrid)
    self.fullmap = np.array(self.occ_gridmap.data)
    self.free_grid=np.where(self.fullmap==0)
    self.width = self.occ_gridmap.info.width
    self.height = self.occ_gridmap.info.height
    self.origin_x = self.occ_gridmap.info.origin.position.x
    self.origin_y = self.occ_gridmap.info.origin.position.y
    
    ...............................
    def cell_grid(self, index):
        e_row = index % self.height
        e_column = ((index - e_row) / self.width)
        return [e_row, e_column]
    
    
    ....................................
    def pose_calculator(self,grid_location):
        x=(grid_location[0]*self.resolution)+self.origin_x
        y=(grid_location[1] * self.resolution) + self.origin_y
        #print("x,y",[x,y])
        return [x,y]
    
    
    ................................
    def mapmaker(self):
        q=[]
    
        for i in range(len(self.free_grid[0])):
            #self.cells.append(self.grid_calculator(self.free_grid[0][i]))
            self.cells.append(self.cell_grid(self.free_grid[0][i]))
        for i in range(len(self.cells)):
            self.cells_array.append(self.pose_calculator(self.cells[i]))
```

As seen above `self.free_grid` is supposed to hold all cells with value `0`(unoccupied cells) and I try to use map,resolution,origin,width and height. The problem is this doesn't seem to work. for instance, when I recalculate occupancy grid data from some of the  poses (x,y) I calculated from `self.free_grid`, I end up with cells that do not have a  value of `0`. Is there a more accurate way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397232/get-pose(x,y)-of-any-unoccupied-cell-from-2d-occupancy-grid/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2022-03-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2022-03-08**:
Are you testing using a square map ? I didn't find issue but indeed when `height != width` the values are incorrect. You have inverted the `width` with the `height` in  `e_row = index % self.height`.

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-03-08**:
@Delb its not a square map, in this case the occupancy grid map in focus has a width of 608 and a height of 384. with resoution of 0.05 I believe. so it should be`e_row=index % self.width`?

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-03-08**:
@Delb and I'm guessing it should be `e_column = ((index - e_row) / self.height)`?  I had thought due to the `int8 [] data` being in row major what I was doing previously was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Row major means that all your data depend on the `width`.

When parsing the data (an array), you start at index `0`, when `index = width - 1` then you have parsed through all the first row. So when `index` is in `[0, width - 1]` : `row = 0` and `column = index`.

Now if you are in the second row then `index` will be in `[width, 2*width - 1]`: `row = 1` and `column = index - width`

For third row index is between `[2*width, 3*width-1]` : `row = 2` and `column = index - 2*width`

We see a pattern here and we can deduce the formula for row and column. The column is always the rest of index minus a multiple of the width, hence a modulo so `column = index % width`. Now this multiple corresponds to the row so  `row = (index - index % width)/width`

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2022-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1